# Is the distance function open?

Tags: general-topology

I know that any distance function is continuous under the topology induced by it. Does it also have to be an open mapping?

Comment: Do you mean open into its image? Otherwise the discrete metric is a counterexample.

Comment: It is quite easy to construct an example of a metric space $(X,d)$ such that  $d(X,X)$ is not open into $\Bbb{R}_{\ge 0}$, for example any compact metric space does the job. Anyway, $d(X,X)$ is open in itself, so it comes to my mind the following interesting question: "is $d:X \times X \to d(X,X)$ an open map?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, look at a discrete space with metric $$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}0 & x=y \\1 &x\neq y\end{cases}$$

Then the image of the distance function of any set containing more than one point is just $\{0,1\}$, which is not an open set in $\mathbb R$.

If you want to view it as a map from $X\times X$ into $d(X,X) \subset \mathbb R_{≥0}$ where $d(X,X)$ is given the subspace topology, then the above example does not work. But the statement is still false. To see it consider $[0,1] \cup \{x,y\}$, where $d\lvert_{[0,1]}$ is the usual metric on $\mathbb R$, $d(x,y)=1$ and $d(x,z)=1=d(y,z)$ for all $z \in [0,1]$.

Then the subspace topology of the image is just the usual topology on $[0,1]$.

But the set $\{x,y\}$ is open and $d(\{x,y\}\times\{x,y\})=\{0,1\}$, which is not open in the image.